# WooCommerce membership plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-memberships

In WooCommerce membership plugin there is a file with name class-wc-memberships-restrictions.php this file have the following class and constructor and that constructor have lots of filters, but I want to remove this filter from my child theme functions.php file

**How can I remove this filter from child theme functions.php file**

```
class WC_Memberships_Restrictions {

public function __construct() {

add_filter( 'the_content',   array( $this, 'restrict_content' ) );

}
```

Comment: Check [`remove_filter()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter) though you will need to know how `WC_Memberships_Restrictions` is initialized.

Comment: how to initialize plugin class in functions.php file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an old copy of Memberships that I had worked on once. An "instance" of the plugin is loaded via the `wc_memberships()` function and the restrictions class is loaded into the `$this->restrictions` class variable. See the main file.

In your `functions.php` you'd do the following to disable it.

```
function so_39668842_remove_membership_restriction(){
    remove_filter( 'the_content', array( wc_memberships()->restrictions, 'restrict_content') );
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'so_39668842_remove_membership_restriction' );
```

Though if your content isn't restricted (post/page settings probably... maybe a global option, I don't remember) you don't need to do this.